# How can I extract the call graph of a function from Python source files?

Tags: python, windows, call-graph

Do you know an integrated tool that will generate the call graph of a function from Python sources? I need one that is consistent and can run on Windows OS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try with [PyCallGraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/)
From its documentation:

> Python Call Graph works with Linux,
>   Windows and Mac OS X.

Otherwise, you can directly do it on your own, using the traceback module:

```
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
```

Comment: This can help but I'm looking for a somewhat graphical code navigation/inspection.

Comment: I think PyCallGraph might just do the job.

Answer (score 9):

PyCallGraph produces the dynamic graph resulting from the specific execution of a Python program and not the static graph extracted from the source code. Does anybody know of a tool which produces the static graph?

Answer (score 6):

What about [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/), it's a Python module that creates call graphs for Python programs. It works on windows.
Just download [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php) and [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/pycallgraph/wiki/documentation/0.5.1/PythonCallGraphInstall), [pycallgraphs's source tarball](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/files/download/pycallgraph-0.5.1.tar.gz) has some examples.
Hope this helps